# How to stop assetic watch in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I followed [the Symfony2 guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) to automatically dump assetic files in dev mode:

- I changed the `use_controller` parameter to `false` in my dev config file.
- And I started the `--watch` routine.

  ```
  $ php app/console assetic:dump --watch
  ```

How can I stop watching?

Comment: Are you using a *nix like shell?

Comment: Actually this question refers to any OS, but I am using Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command looking for file changes only while it working itself. So then you stop command - no more automatic regenerating assets.

On linux its typical ctrl+c or ctrl+x

P.S. some code from [DumpCommand](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/2.3/Command/DumpCommand.php)

```
while (true) {
    try {
        foreach ($this->am->getNames() as $name) {
            if ($this->checkAsset($name, $previously)) {
                $this->dumpAsset($name, $output);
            }
        }

        // reset the asset manager
        $prop->setValue($this->am, array());
        $this->am->load();

        file_put_contents($cache, serialize($previously));
        $error = '';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($error != $msg = $e->getMessage()) {
            $output->writeln('<error>[error]</error> '.$msg);
            $error = $msg;
        }
    }
    sleep($input->getOption('period'));
}
```

Comment: I'm using his way too on linux console.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Im add some code from command, i think its very clear

Comment: It's your business. I can not convince you, but think about the meaning of infinite loop in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Like @forgottenbas points out the code runs in an infinite loop so it's not *really* a background worker but simply a worker that occupies your shell until an outside force intervenes.

Generally the developer can kill the process or the shell session it's occupying.

On OSX <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> sends `SIGKILL`, for instance.

In Windows it seems to work a bit differently in Window shells: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)#Microsoft_Windows

It's definitely OS, or more accurately, shell dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spawned a linux background process, e.g.:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --watch &
```

you have to kill the php process that is running